# Save mysql value locally if internet connection lost

Tags: php, mysql

I am designing a system that collects a customer's signature once a job has been completed by an engineer at the customer's premises.  Everything is working great, it is a `PHP` and `MySQL` based system and the signature is entered using a touch screen and the image is converted to `JSON` and saved in the database as a string.

However, there may be times when the internet connection is lost or unavailable but the signature still needs to be collected and I was wondering if there was a method that anyone knows of that can save a `PHP` value locally ready to be uploaded once an internet connect is re established? Perhaps using cookies?

Comment: don't write a full question. just search with some keywords and get a look around: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=browser+offline+storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the data in local storage. Check chapter from [dive into html5](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html) about offline apps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

[How do I create and read a value from cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

With cookies you can do that. But you still need to figure out how you'll check if the internet conection has gone.

Comment: this is the wrong answer for the images in question. at least highly likely.